# Navigation drawer in all Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

Hi all i want to put navigation drawer in all activity.

**Layout file:**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In other activity i am extending this class. But this this not working only this is the drawer logo is coming in the other activity page.

Please tell what i am doing wrong here.
**Thanks in advance.**

***I find the solution. Thanks for your kind help.***

***Update:***

**Please find my answer below.**

Comment: @deniz please check my updated code still its not working

Comment: please post your answer.. I also same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout `drawer_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
```

**drwaer_custom_layout_file** This is for each single row in drawer.(Customize based on requirement):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemLayoutColor"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/sku_search"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/dividerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#191919"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp" >
</View>
```

**Create an `Adapter` class. (*Remove the element which is not relevant for you)*:**

```
public class CustomDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem> {

Context context;
List<DrawerItem> drawerItemList;
int layoutResID;
int selectedPosition;


public CustomDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,
        List<DrawerItem> listItems, int selectedPosition) {
    super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.drawerItemList = listItems;
    this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;
    this.selectedPosition = selectedPosition;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();

        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
        drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemName);
        drawerHolder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);
        drawerHolder.itemLayoutColor = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.itemLayoutColor);
        // drawerHolder.dividerView = (View) view
        // .findViewById(R.id.dividerView);
        view.setTag(drawerHolder);

    } else {
        drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    DrawerItem dItem = (DrawerItem) this.drawerItemList.get(position);
    drawerHolder.ItemName.setTypeface(tfNormal);
    drawerHolder.ItemName.setText(dItem.getItemName());
    if (dItem.getImgResID() != 0) {
        drawerHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(
                dItem.getImgResID()));

    } else {

        drawerHolder.ItemName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.black));
        drawerHolder.itemLayoutColor.setBackgroundColor(context
                .getResources().getColor(R.color.pGray));
        drawerHolder.icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // drawerHolder.dividerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    if(selectedPosition == position){
        drawerHolder.itemLayoutColor.setBackgroundColor(context
                .getResources().getColor(R.color.lightyellow));
    }
    return view;
}

private static class DrawerItemHolder {
    TextView ItemName;
    ImageView icon;
    LinearLayout itemLayoutColor;
    // View dividerView;
}
}
```

**Create a class that will `extends` `Activity` write below methods:**

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.navigation_drawer_layout, null);
    actContent = (FrameLayout) mDrawerLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);
    super.setContentView(mDrawerLayout);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
    }
    return true;
}

protected void navigationDrawer(DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout,
        ListView mDrawerList, int selectedPosition) {

    this.selectedPosition = selectedPosition;

    activity = (Activity) NavigationDrawerBaseActivity.this;
    actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    this.mDrawerLayout = mDrawerLayout;
    this.mDrawerList = mDrawerList;

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

    **********Here add the items in the list***********
   i.e.
    mDataList.add(new DrawerItem(DrawerConstant.LOGOUT,
            R.drawable.ic_signout));

    adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this,
            R.layout.drawer_custom_single_layout, mDataList,
            selectedPosition);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}

public class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

            if (position != selectedPosition) {
                selectItem(position);
    }
}

protected void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        // Call the another activity
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        break;
    case 1:
        // Call the another activity
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        break;
    case 2:
        // Call the another activity
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
  }
 }
```

**Add the below code in Activity wherever you want to put Navigation Drawer:**

- Extends the `NavigationDrawerBaseActivity` class.
- After `setContentView` call below method:

  ```
  // set Naviagtion Drawer
  DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  ListView mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
  super.navigationDrawer(mDrawerLayout, mDrawerList, 1);
  ```
- Add below method in same `Activity`:

  ```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a BaseActivity class that implements the drawer, and let all your activities extend this BaseActivity.

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); 
    actContent = (FrameLayout) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.frame_container);

    setContentView(mDrawerLayout);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);
}
```

Set the drawer layout as main content

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the asked scenario in the following procedure.

**Xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/venue_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayoutContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/ExpandableList"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@drawable/left_drawer_item_gradient"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

        <!-- content layout -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**setcontentView inside NavigationDrawerBaseActivity**

```
@Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutID) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        fullLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_menu_activity_container, null);

        pocketFrame = (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutContent);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutID, pocketFrame, true);

        super.setContentView(fullLayout);
    }
```

In your `NavigationDrawerBaseActivity` make a method which sets setcontentView & take layout as an argument, & in every extended child class override that method & pass layout in argument. In xml @+id/ExpandableList is a list which is in left & @+id/frameLayoutContent acts like a container for incoming argument layouts, this will give you the replica of fraqgments replacing in a container.

**Note**: This is just a work around, recommended is Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an abstract method to get the layout for the activity which it's extending your navigation drawer: `public abstract int NavigatonDrawerBaseActivity();` and make your class an abstract class (here use `setContentView(NavigatonDrawerBaseActivity())`). Then in the class which it's extending the Navigation drawer implements the method and pass it your xml layout (not use the setContentView method):

```
@Override
public int NavigatonDrawerBaseActivity() {

    return R.layout.yourLayout;
}
```

And finally in your layout you need to add the same code of your NavigationDrawerBaseActivity xml:

This works form me using fragments. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
public class MyDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
protected RelativeLayout fullLayout;
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
@Override
public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
    fullLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mydrawer, null);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);
    super.setContentView(fullLayout);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout3);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), menuItem.getTitle().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_5_reasons).setChecked(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:id="@+id/drawer_framelayout">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_frame2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
android:background="#fefefd" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

for use:

```
public class yourclass extends MyDrawer {
```

is .setOnItemClickListener  work?yes

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<FrameLayout>
    your main content stuff here
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<FrameLayout>
    your main content stuff here(.setOnItemClickListener)
```