# why my navigationdrawer dose not work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-navigation

when i open the app my content view ("hello world") is not displayed. just listview appears but it must be shown when i swipe. here is my codes:

```
package com.example.temp;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);      

        ListView drawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.first);
        String[] myStringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.right1); 
        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myStringArray));    


        final ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation = "vertical">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:gravity="left" >
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and my strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">temp</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>


<string-array name="right1">
    <item name="1*1">1*1</item>
    <item name="1*2">1*2</item>
    <item name="1*3">1*3</item>
    <item name="1*4">1*4</item>
    <item name="1*5">1*5</item>
    <item name="1*6">1*6</item>
    <item name="1*7">1*7</item>
    <item name="1*8">1*8</item>
    <item name="1*9">1*9</item>
</string-array>
```

[image]

Comment: can you show some snap how it look like ?

Comment: @SilentKiller i added screenshot !!!

Comment: have a look at the xml here I suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499012/navigation-drawer-in-all-activity/25499144#25499144

Comment: use `android:layout_gravity="start"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="left"`

Comment: yes use Start.. I have also used start in the suggested link

Comment: @SilentKiller no still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an incorrect attribute in your ListView xml definition.

```
 android:gravity="left"
```

should be

```
 android:layout_gravity="left"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Its working code.

Activity Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"


    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

In the frame you can Load any Fragment using the Fragment Manager. That fragment can have the linear layout that you have mentioned.

Comment: i got the answer but +1 for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

**The easier way to create a Navigation Drawer.**

- Create an android app with Blank Activity.
- Select your package right
  click on it & then select "New" -> Others -> select "Android
  Activity" & then select "Navigation Drawer Activity".

This will create you a NavigationDrawer for you.
Enjoy

[image]